# What is port 1001 used by NT Kernel & System on my Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, services, netstat

Sometimes i make ssh tunnel which listen as sock proxy on port 1001.
But lately i can't bind to this port. Apparently this port already occupied.
I can bind to any port for my ssh tunnel. But I'm curious who use this port.
Because it's just happen recently. This port never used for many years since I'm using my laptop. 
FYI I'm not install anything recently. Last time I install software is about six month ago. This problem just occurred about a week ago.

I'm trying to locate it using tcpview, its just give information it's run by NT Kernel & System (PID 4). I also try to look at windows services and task scheduler, nothing suspicious.

I can't find anything with netstat either

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:1001         -----:0            LISTENING
Can not obtain ownership information
```

Quick search on google this port can be used by many trojan.
So i did run rootkit scanner from malwarebytes and karspersky. Nothing come out. I'm using avast antivirus, and its run all the time.

This is my running service (net start):

```
AFBAgent
AMD External Events Utility
Application Experience
Application Layer Gateway Service
ASLDR Service
ATKGFNEX Service
Avast Antivirus
Background Intelligent Transfer Service
Base Filtering Engine
Bluetooth Service
CNG Key Isolation
COM+ Event System
Computer Browser
Cryptographic Services
DCOM Server Process Launcher
Desktop Window Manager Session Manager
DHCP Client
Diagnostic Policy Service
Diagnostic Service Host
Distributed Link Tracking Client
DNS Client
Extensible Authentication Protocol
Function Discovery Provider Host
Function Discovery Resource Publication
Group Policy Client
HomeGroup Listener
HomeGroup Provider
Intel(R) Management & Security Application User Notification Service
Intel(R) Management and Security Application Local Management Service
Internet Connection Sharing (ICS)
IP Helper
Nalpeiron Licensing Service
Network Connections
Network List Service
Network Location Awareness
Network Store Interface Service
Offline Files
Peer Name Resolution Protocol
Peer Networking Grouping
Peer Networking Identity Manager
Plug and Play
Portable Device Enumerator Service
Power
Print Spooler
Program Compatibility Assistant Service
Remote Access Auto Connection Manager
Remote Access Connection Manager
Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
RPC Endpoint Mapper
Secure Socket Tunneling Protocol Service
Security Accounts Manager
Security Center
Server
Shell Hardware Detection
SSDP Discovery
Superfetch
System Event Notification Service
Task Scheduler
TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper
Telephony
Themes
UPnP Device Host
USB Safely Remove Assistant
User Profile Service
Windows Audio
Windows Audio Endpoint Builder
Windows Defender
Windows Driver Foundation - User-mode Driver Framework
Windows Event Log
Windows Firewall
Windows Font Cache Service
Windows Image Acquisition (WIA)
Windows Management Instrumentation
Windows Update
WLAN AutoConfig
Workstation
WWAN AutoConfig
```

Does anyone know who usually use this tcp port 1001?

Comment: Something that isn't built into Windows since your connecting to the localhost

Comment: Its not connecting, it's listening.